# How can I read push notification from other apps?

Tags: android

I want to make an app which can read all of the push notification the device get and sort them.
And I want to know if I can access to the other application's push notification content.

Comment: No you can't access other app's push.

Answer (score 8):

If by "push notification", you mean `Notification` objects populating the status bar, you can create [a `NotificationListenerService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) for this. Users may not be interested in giving your app the rights to monitor their notifications, though, which is why the user must manually enable this for your app.

If by "push notification" you mean something like Google Cloud Messaging, you cannot intercept push messages destined for other apps, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going to make an app automatically saves amount of money I used.

Comment: Minseo, have you got solutions,  could you please help here, I'm also working on similar kinds of idea.