# Can I read others push notifications on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

The main tread here, but is from 6 years ago ([How can I read push notification from other apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114461/how-can-i-read-push-notification-from-other-apps))

I'm making an app and I was thinking if is possible to read all of the push notification the device and get their data. (push notifications of others apps)

I know it is possible on Android. Is there any update for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR. No

---

APNs delivers remote notifications based on a token, generated by an app. The token at each moment of time is unique to the app instance, installed at the specific device. Only the app instance associated with the token is delivered with corresponding remote notifications.